# Exception has occurred: TypeError

Tags: python

Could you help me with this error?

Exception has occurred: TypeError AbstractStore.put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given   File "C:\Users\Nilkn\Desktop\p10\proj2\main.py", line 22, in build     self.moveis = self.store.get('moveis') or {}                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'moveis'  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    File "C:\Users\Nilkn\Desktop\p10\proj2\main.py", line 24, in build     self.store.put('moveis', {})   File "C:\Users\Nilkn\Desktop\p10\proj2\main.py", line 94, in <module>     LogisticaApp().run() TypeError: AbstractStore.put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'dock')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.behaviors.focus import FocusBehavior

class MyTextInput(TextInput, FocusBehavior):
    pass
class LogisticaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.store = JsonStore('moveis.json')
        try:
            self.moveis = self.store.get('moveis') or {}
        except KeyError:
            self.store.put('moveis', {})
            self.moveis = {}
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.modelo_label = Label(text="Modelo")
        layout.add_widget(self.modelo_label)
        self.modelo_entry = MyTextInput()
        layout.add_widget(self.modelo_entry)
        self.tamanho_label = Label(text="Tamanho")
        layout.add_widget(self.tamanho_label)
        self.tamanho_entry = MyTextInput()
        layout.add_widget(self.tamanho_entry)
        self.cor_label = Label(text="Cor")
        layout.add_widget(self.cor_label)
        self.cor_entry = MyTextInput()
        layout.add_widget(self.cor_entry)
        self.localizacao_label = Label(text="Localização")
        layout.add_widget(self.localizacao_label)
        self.localizacao_entry = MyTextInput()
        layout.add_widget(self.localizacao_entry)
        self.resultado_label = Label(text="")
        layout.add_widget(self.resultado_label)
        self.consulta_button = Button(text="Consultar", on_press=self.consulta)
        layout.add_widget(self.consulta_button)

        self.cadastro_button = Button(text="Cadastrar", on_press=self.cadastro)
        layout.add_widget(self.cadastro_button)
        return layout
    def on_stop(self):
        self.store.put('moveis', self.moveis)
    def consulta(self, instance):
        modelo = self.modelo_entry.text.lower()
        tamanho = self.tamanho_entry.text
        cor = self.cor_entry.text
        if modelo in self.moveis:
            if tamanho and cor:
                mensagem = f"{self.moveis[modelo]['localizacao']}: {tamanho} {cor}"
            elif tamanho:
                mensagem = f"{self.moveis[modelo]['localizacao']}: {tamanho}"
            elif cor:
                mensagem = f"{self.moveis[modelo]['localizacao']}: {cor}"
            else:
                mensagem = self.moveis[modelo]['localizacao']
            self.resultado_label.text = f" {mensagem}"
        else:
            self.resultado_label.text = f"O móvel {modelo} não está cadastrado"
    def cadastro(self, instance):
        modelo = self.modelo_entry.text.lower()  # converte para minúsculas
        tamanho = self.tamanho_entry.text
        cor = self.cor_entry.text
        localizacao = self.localizacao_entry.text

        if modelo and len(modelo) >= 2:  # verifica se o modelo não está em branco e tem pelo menos 2 caracteres
            self.moveis[modelo] = {'tamanho': tamanho, 'cor': cor, 'localizacao': localizacao}
            self.resultado_label.text = "Móvel cadastrado com sucesso"
        else:
            self.resultado_label.text = "O modelo deve ter pelo menos 2 caracteres"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LogisticaApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is `TypeError: AbstractStore.put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

This means `AbstractStore.put` expects you to pass 1 parameter when you call it but you have passed in 2 (in addition to what you pass, a default parameter - self or cls is always passed).

The fix is that instead of passing 2 parameters - a key ('movies') and a value ({}), you should only pass 1 (a dictionary which has a key and the value is empty) i.e.

**change** `self.store.put('moveis', {})` to `self.store.put({'moveis': {}})`.